# Является ли изменение ViewModel в Command хорошей практикой для ReactiveUI?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть `DataGrid` с столбцами `FirstProperty`, `SecondProperty`, .., `FifthProperty` , в `ItemsSource` задан `ReactiveList<SomeType>`

Юзер сам заполняет DataGrid. После заполнения ему нужно нажать на кнопку, что приводит к выполнению вот такой команды:

```
SomeCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<ReactiveList<SomeType>, bool[]>(async (someObjects, cancellationToken) =>
    {
        foreach (var someObject in someObjects)
        {
            var data =  DoLongOperation(someObject.FirstProperty, someObject.SecondProperty, someObject.ThirdProperty, cancellationToken); 
            someObject.FifthProperty = data;
        }
    });
```

У меня есть сомнения насчет того, что это (изменение ViewModel в Command) хорошая практика для ReactiveUI. Так ли это? Если нет - как изменить этот код?

Comment: А где еще вы можете менять ViewModel-то?

Comment: В Subscribe, но не в этом случае.

Comment: Т.е. вы не видите здесь ничего плохого? Я просто еще не проникся реактивным программированием.

Comment: Нормально. Реактивное программирование здесь ни при чём.